# How to stop process fdhost?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, kill-process

I'm trying to update SQL Server 2016 to CU7.

During the *Files in Use* check, I'm prompted to stop `fdhost.exe` for each running instance in order to prevent the need for a reboot.

But how to stop this process? I've stopped the Full-text Filter service and `fdhost.exe` is still running. When I kill it in Task Manager (or by using `taskkill`) it comes right back with a new PID and the service restarts itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Setup was misreporting the need for a reboot.

I proceeded with the installation and it completed successfully. No reboot prompt.